# Visual Studio 2019 and ASP.NET project not starting

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2019, .net-4.8

I have an issue with VS 2019 and **any** ASP.NET application, they don't want to start. After hitting F5 there is no output in the Output window, Process Memory stops on 13 MB and that's all, no events, nothing. It was working fine and I'm having a problem investigating what's gone wrong that it stopped working.
I have checked that IIS Express is working fine, repaired VS twice, updated it, there are no errors in Event Log, restarted PC, reinstalled .NET Framework.
Running other types of applications like console works fine, no issues there.

The problem is that I can't find any piece of information that would help me to define what is wrong.

How can I troubleshoot more to find what is wrong?

Comment: If any newly created project(asp .net application) doesn’t work, you may need to consider reinstalling VS as a last resort. Before trying this, you can do some troubleshooting, such as disable installed extensions temporarily, [reset VS settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/environment-settings?view=vs-2019#reset-settings), and report this issue to Microsoft([Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=8&entry=problem)) if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem with my Blazor App, after a colleague of mine googled around a bit it seemed like there was some kind of bug in later versions of VS2019. I decided to switch to the 2022 preview and here it worked fine again.